# Converting polygon to line in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, line

When I'm doing `"polygon to line"` analysis on ArcGIS the result is individual line features but in QGIS is not.

How can I execute `"polygon to line"` in QGIS where each polygon becomes individual line feature?

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `Explode lines` tool to explode the converted line feature into individual lines:

[image]

Search for `Explode lines` in the processing toolbox and you will find it. 
I am using QGIS 3.4.

Comment: 3.14? My, you must be a traveller from the future, dear Sir!

Comment: @Erik Thanks for your comment. It looks like yes, I was coming from the future :). I updated the answer.

Comment: @DamarPanoto If the answer solved your problem, please accept the answer.